# Android recyclerView HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview in wich each row contains an url, and the urls can expire in any moment. 
I would like the user to not be forced to click on the url to check if it's not valid but I'd rather change the row's color in that case to notify the user.

This is the method I use to check if the url is still valid:

```
private boolean isUrlStillValid(String url) {
    try {

        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "");

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        con.disconnect();

        return responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;

    }catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I initially thought of launching an AsyncTask in the onBindViewHolder method of the recycler view where I check the url validity, but this will open a lot of connections simultaneously every time a row is shown and will cause very bad performance and memory issues I think.

Do you have any tip/suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you have any tip/suggestions on how to achieve this?

for each url create a runnable and run all of them on fix thread pool with [ExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

for example you can have 5 threads at a time with below code:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
```

and also I recommend to save the result somewhere so when the user plays with scrollbar it dose not check the url again and again and again ...

Comment: Also, when response arrives, make sure you update the information on the correct view holder. (it might be recycled to represent another position)

Comment: Shouldn't I implement what you suggest with AsyncTasks and executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)? And if I have something like 100 rows can't be there any memory/performance issues?

Comment: "Shouldn't I implement what you suggest with AsyncTasks and executeOnExecutor?" you can do that. "And if I have something like 100 rows can't be there any memory/performance issues?" Yes, there is a problem with performance not memory, because all 100 rows are going to be queued if the user scrolls to the end of your list but dequeued for example 5 at a time, actually you have a problem and must cancel previous task if the list is recycling.